# What is the default data directory for mongodb if we install that in amazon ec2

Tags: default, mongodb

I tried to find this info everywhere and couldn't find it. I already change mongodb.conf so I forget where the original directory is.

Answer (score 6):

When you are searching a file in your filesystem while you are running Ubuntu a very easy way to find it is to do the following:

1. Update the database with your files (may be a bit slow, depending on when it run the last time automatically from your system):

   ```
   sudo updatedb
   ```
2. Search for the corresponding file (super quick):

   ```
   locate mongodb.conf
   ```

The config file name has recently change, now use `locate mongod.conf` (no more "b") (or just `locate '*mongo*.conf'`, if you aren't sure).

**Note**: In the latest mongodb versions, the configuration file has been renamed to `mongod.conf`

Comment: The config file name has recently change, now use "locate mongod.conf" (no more "b")

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Locate hasn't any output.

Comment: @OddDev the file has been renamed to `mongod.conf`. In my installation it's placed at `/etc/mongod.conf`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure for amazon ec2 exactly but on my machine it is located at  /var/lib/mongodb

Answer (score -1):

IMO finding files with locate isn't the best approach, since you have to know the identical name of the file you're searching

Try instead

```
find / -name 'mondo*.conf'
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`locate`'s manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mlocate.1.html)? It supports both wildcards and regular expressions.

Comment: You are right, I haven't - yet you could've gave an example of its usage in the same scenario.

Comment: `locate '*mongo*.conf'`, or simply: `locate mongo`.

Comment: This is also good answer, not every developer has sudo permission to run ```sudo updatedb```

Answer (score -1):

You can find MongoDB configuration:
locate '*mongo*.conf'
Also this is the MongoDB resource:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please add appropriate citations when your answer incorporates  a part of another answer. For discussion about why see [this meta question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4196/how-should-we-handle-plagiarized-answers). If your answer would not stand on its own consider: suggesting an edit, or expanding your answer.